# What's the _wp_desired_post_slug value for?

Tags: plugins, redirect

I'm trying to debug a 301 redirect that is causing me lots of trouble. I renamed a page from `/blog` to `/old-blog` and created a new page with the `/blog` slug. Now I'm getting 301 redirects from `/blog` to `/old-blog`. I already tried to look for the value in the `wp_postmeta` table with the `meta_key` `*_wp_old_slug*` but it isn't showing up.

I did found 2 entries with the blog `meta_value` under the `*_wp_desired_post_slug*` meta_key. What are these values supposed to be for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this line in WordPress core](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a2693fd8602e3263b5925b9d799ddd577202167d/wp-includes/post.php#L3302).

**Explanation:** When you move a post to the trash, `_wp_desired_post_slug` holds the slug that was desired for that post (now in the trash); i.e., when you move a post to the trash, WordPress suffixes the old slug so that it becomes available again, but it remembers the slug that you desired, just in case you decide to move it out of the trash and restore it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At the end, my problem wasn't related to that value but is good to know from now on that this doesn't cause any slug-related problem.